# Interpretation of a difficult sentence involving "二人の間に入ってしまった"

Tags: grammar

I'm trying to figure out the proper interpretation for a line within a story. Here is the line:

> 偶像としての彼女の姿の揺らぎと、僕自身が生々しい二人の間に入ってしまったからだ

I think properly understanding this will require context, so here is the paragraph this line is embedded in, as well as the previous one:

> 何はともあれ、もう来ない、ということはなさそうだ。事の詳細はよくわからないが、落木部さんに入れ込んでいるようだし、マネージャーさんとの不仲はともかく、それはそれ、これはこれと区別するような人だろう。爽快なほどサバサバしている。
>
> ただ、それは本人の中の話であって、一連の話を聞いた僕の頭の中はどうにもすっきりしない。**偶像としての彼女の姿の揺らぎと、僕自身が生々しい二人の間に入ってしまったからだ**。もう知らないふりはできないだろうし、お客さんというイニシアチブを取られている以上、綺羅めくるに加担するしかない。

However, I still think this may not be enough context, so let me explain the situation.

落木部さん: girl who works at a cafe where the main character has just started working a few weeks ago.

綺羅めくる: was previously a pop idol, but lost popularity several years ago. Sister to 落木部さん. She is the subject of the first paragraph.

マネージャー: manager to 綺羅めくる, who doublecrossed her by secretly working with a new girl who became the new pop star, just as 綺羅めくる lost popularity.

Now, taking apart the phrase in question:

偶像としての彼女の姿の揺らぎと: This seems to be the changing (literally 'flickering') of main character's image/impression of 綺羅めくる, as he has learned more about her struggles to obtain and maintain fame.

生々しい: Says 'vivid' in the dictionary, but not sure how
this is used here. Maybe the sense of 'in the flesh'?

二人: This is one of my biggest problems with this sentence. There are three people discussed in the previous paragraph and I don't know which two are involved.

の間に入ってしまった: I think this literally means 'to come between', but I think the usage is actually psychological.

Finally, in addition to the confusion with the above parts, I am not sure how this sentence connects to the previous one, where the main character seems to be bothered by the situation ("...すっきりしない")

My guess at interpretation is that the sentence in question means that the main character somehow is now "involved" in a "real" sense, and due to his involvement he cannot stand by without helping 綺羅めくる. But I am not very certain about this.

[Here](http://ncode.syosetu.com/n6899db/6/) is the entire chapter for context. The phrase is near the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence in question is not really well-organized, but at least understandable without ambiguity. First, the と after 揺らぎ is connecting two reasons. The sentence can be rephrased as:

> （僕がすっきりしない原因は、）ひとつには偶像としての彼女の姿が揺らいでしまったからであり、もうひとつには僕自身が生々しい二人の間に入ってしまったからだ。

As for the first reason, 揺らぐ has a negative connotation (lose stability, stumble. See [my previous answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/19270/5010)). The good image of 綺羅めくる which the main character held has been *negatively* affected during the conversation.

As for the second reason, obviously he's referring to the complicated relationship between めくる and her manager (都). 落木部さん doesn't play an important role in this chapter. ～の間に入ってしまった in this context means to end up being involved. 生々しい here has a bit of negative nuance like "(too) realistic", "overly uncovered". For example one can say 「夢を語っているときに、お金の話は生々しいからやめて！」「生々しい芸能界の[闇](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/43591/5010)」「生々しい話をすると、ディズニーランドのミッキーマウスの中には人間が入っている」.

Comment: Thank you Naruto sensei for the excellent answer. It was mainly the fact that the 揺らぎ was a separate reason that tripped me up. 助かりました！